# Is there any consistent theory for multivariate multiple regression?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Given $X \in R^{n*p}$, representing the regression coefficients as an $p*k$ matrix $B^*$. the multivariate multiple regression model takes the form
$Y=XB^* + W$, 
where $Y\in R^{n*k}$ denotes the multiple response matrix and $W\in R^{n*k}$ are matrices of zero-mean noise, respectively.

G. Obozinski, M. J. Wainwright, and M. I. Jordan.
Support union recovery in high-dimensional multivariate regression. The Annals of Statistics, 39(1):1–47, 2011.

The THEOREM 1 (Eq.(20)) of this paper provides an upper bound between the multivariate group Lasso solution $\hat{B}$ and regression matrix $B^*$.

The upper bound depends on the correlations of design matrices $X$, however, does not consider the relations of response matrix $Y$.

For multivariate multiple regression, is there any references providing the consistent theory or support recovery theory considering the relations of response matrix $Y$?

Comment: You might consider posting this on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ too.